# .net core 1.1 angular 5 windows authentication 401 unauthorized

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, proxy, .net-core

I have a web api with the iis authentication turn on in order to extricate the windows user_name.

In order to develop with my angular app I have to run it on the localhost.
Each time I try to do a post my webapi I get 401 unauthorized.

What can I do?
Can I use a proxy?

**update**

I have come a cross with this bit of code for porxy:

```
    const Agent = require('agentkeepalive');

module.exports = {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:59465',
            secure: false,
            agent: new Agent({
                maxSockets: 100,
                keepAlive: true,
                maxFreeSockets: 10,
                keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                timeout: 6000000,
                keepAliveTimeout: 90000
            }),
            onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
                let key = 'www-authenticate';
                proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
                    proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
            }
        }
};
```

This proxy all ready create an authenticate call so I did not needed to authenticate my calls to the web api.

I found it here:
https://www.meekdeveloper.com/angular-cli-asp-net-core-windows-authentication/

Comment: Which authentication method are you using? Can you provide us a sample code?

Comment: Perhaps that is my problem. I have no authentication method. I need to have windows authentication on the iis site in order to send my user name to another service but when I call my web api I have no authentication

Comment: So you need to get the current windows logged user, right?

Comment: why? do you think I need to authenticate my http call to my first web api with my current windows user?